# undefined method `value' for #<CategoryItemValue::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ff9706d24c0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is so simple but isnt working. What am I missing?

controlelr

```
 @guide      = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
 @category   = @guide.categories.friendly.find params[:id]
 @items      = @category.category_items
```

view

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.category_item_values.value %>
<% end %>
```

gives the no method error of

`undefined method 'value' for #<CategoryItemValue::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ff9706d24c0>`

There is a `values` column in the `category_item_values` table so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item.category_item_values` is the `CollectionProxy` instance (one might think of it as of an kinda array.)

Each `category_item` has [likely, you did not provide sufficiently enough info to guess more precisely] many values. If the assumption above is correct, here you go:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <% item.category_item_values.each do |value| %>
    <%= value %> # or maybe (depending on your model) <%= value.value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just got a quick kind of unrelated question. If I store a record like in a variable like `jon = User.find(3) `and call the variable a few times on a page like `jon.name` is that faster than just using `User.find(3).name` 3 times or does it still perform the db lookup each time the variable is used?

Comment: Well, yes. This technique is named “caching.” Instead of three queries against database the code will perform only one.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop over each of the `category_item_values` to get the result as this suggests `<CategoryItemValue::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ff9706d24c0>` that your category_item_value is a association.

So you could do something like

```
<% item.category_item_values.each do |category_item_value| %>
  <%= category_item_value.value %>
<% end %>
```